# Strings pulled from Regex apear to match but dont

Tags: ruby, regex, selenium, testunit

This doesn't make any sense to me.  I am trying to assert that these two dates are the same.  They look the same but somehow they are different.

```
#assert correct time and date
assert_equal(/[0-9]{1,2}, [0-9]{4} at [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2} [A-Z]{2}/.match($driver.find_element(:class, "flash-information").text), /[0-9]{1,2}, [0-9]{4} at [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2} [A-Z]{2}/.match($driver.find_element(:class, "news_date").text))
```

Here is the failure I get.

```
F
===============================================================================
Failure: <#<MatchData "10, 2013 at 4:13 PM">> expected but was
<#<MatchData "10, 2013 at 4:13 PM">>. 

   39:     #assert correct time and date
=> 40:     assert_equal(/[0-9]{1,2}, [0-9]{4} at [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2} [A-Z]{2}/.match($driver.find_element(:class, "flash-information").text), /[0-9]{1,2}, [0-9]{4} at [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2} [A-Z]{2}/.match($driver.find_element(:class, "news_date").text))
```

I am running this inside Test Unit

Comment: Please be more specific on the title (e.g. we should expect what exactly your question is by the title)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not matching strings, you're matching `MatchData` objects.

```
a = "foobar".match /f/   # #<MatchData "f">
b = "foobar".match /f/   # #<MatchData "f">
c = "barfoo".match /f/   # #<MatchData "f">

a == b   # true
a == c   # false
```

If you want to compare matched *strings*, then you have to extract them from the `MatchData` object:

```
a[0]           # "f"
a[0] == b[0]   # true
a[0] == c[0]   # true
```

Comment: Thanks, So it is comparing the exact instance of the object?

Comment: No. It's comparing the matched string, matched groups, start and end position, and regular expression used. In my example, start and end position don't match, so it's a `false`. To see for yourself, go to http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/MatchData.html#method-i-3D-3D, float cursor over the `mtch == mtch2` line, and "click to toggle source" will show. Click it to toggle source, and you can inspect for yourself exactly what it does.